openai.ChatCompletion issue
Seems I'm another person affected by the OpenAI migration issue. Can you please help me?
The full error:
OpenAI API error: You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API. You can run openai migrate to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. pip install openai==0.28 A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
My app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import openai  # Importing openai directly
import configparser

# Read configurations from config.ini
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# Check if the required OpenAI API key is present in the configuration
if 'OpenAI' not in config or 'api_key' not in config['OpenAI']:
    raise ValueError("OpenAI API key not found in config.ini")

# Initialize the OpenAI client
openai.api_key = config['OpenAI']['api_key']

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    # Render the chat.html template when the root URL is accessed
    return render_template('chat.html')

@app.route('/send', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    # Get the user's message from the request
    user_message = request.json.get('message', '')

    # Placeholder character info 
    character_info = {
        "name": "Unknown Character",
        "appearance": {
            "body_type": "Unknown",
            "complexion": "Unknown"
        },
        "bio": {
            "House_of_Ashes": "Unknown",
            "accident": "Unknown"
        },
        "traits": "Unknown"
    }

    # Update the prompt to include character details
    prompt = config['Prompt']['prompt'].format(
        name=character_info['name'],
        traits=character_info['traits'],
        appearance=character_info['appearance'],
        bio=character_info['bio'],
        conversation_summary=''
    )

    # Construct the conversation format for the OpenAI API
    conversation = [
        {"role": "system", "content": f"You are {character_info['name']}, and you are talking to {user_message}."},
        {"role": "user", "content": user_message}
    ]

    try:
        # Debug: print the conversation being sent to OpenAI API
        print("Sending conversation to OpenAI API:", conversation)

        # Call the OpenAI API to process the user's message and get a response
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model=config['LanguageModel']['model'],
            messages=conversation
        )

        # Debug: print the response received from OpenAI API
        print("Received response from OpenAI API:", response)

        bot_response = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle API errors
        print("Error:", str(e))  # Debug: print the error
        return jsonify(response="OpenAI API error: " + str(e))

    # Update the conversation summary with the latest interaction
    prompt = prompt.replace('{conversation_summary}', f'Player: {user_message}\nCharacter: {bot_response}\n')

    # Return the bot's response as JSON
    return jsonify(response=bot_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


ChatGPT doesn't help, I've tried running the solutions listed in the link from the error and that didn't work too.

Please see OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0".

Please read the official Python OpenAI package docs
The minimal usage example is like this:
import os
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
    # This is the default and can be omitted
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
)

chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Say this is a test",
        }
    ],
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
)


Sorry - I'm a self-learning beginner and tbh implementing this causes me troubles since the example in the documentation differs from what I've written, heh.
